# Error in table alignment

Tags: tables, alignment

The following code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{myGray}{HTML}{F2F2F2}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\columncolor{myGray}\centering$}m{6mm}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering$}m{6mm}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|G|M|M|M|M|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{myGray} \times & 1 & i & j & k \\\hline
    1 & 1 & i & j & k \\\hline
    i & i & -1 & k & -j \\\hline
    j & j & -k & -1 & i \\\hline
    k & k & j & -i & -1 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

creates this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 ...rowcolor{myGray} \times & 1 & i & j & k \\
                                                  \hline
```

When I modified the alignment of the table from `{|G|M|M|M|M|}` to `{|G|M|M|M|m|}`, it does work. But I think that the definition of `M` isn't wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE.

Comment: You need to (a) load the `array` package (to enable the macro `\newcolumntype`) and (b) replace both instances of `\centering` with `\centering\arraybackslash`. Separately, do also replace `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} \usepackage{colortbl}` with `\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}` in order to assure optimal interoperability of the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages.

Comment: @Mico Thanks very much! It works very well now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the LaTeX macro `\centerig` redefines `\\`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\centering{%
  \let\\\@centercr  %% <<< this is re-definition of \\
  \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue
  \finalhyphendemerits=\z@
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
\protected\def\@centercr{\ifhmode \unskip\else \@nolnerr\fi
       \par\@ifstar{\nobreak\@xcentercr}\@xcentercr}
\gdef\@nolnerr{%
  \@latex@error{There's no line here to end}\@eha}
```

The test `\ifhmode` fails because you are in math mode when `\\` occurs.

One solution is not to use `\centering` macro but TeX primitive `\hfil` because you want to center only single-line paragraphs:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hfil $}m{6mm}<{$}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To your problem (defining column types) you can avoided on more ways:

- consider @Mico comment,
- consider @wipet answer,
- instead of `\\` use `\tabularnewline`
- and also by use of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myGray}{HTML}{F2F2F2}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c,bg=myGray, mode=math] *{4}{Q[c, mode=math]}},
             row{1} = {bg=myGray}
             }
\times  & 1 &  i &  j &  k  \\ 
    1   & 1 &  i &  j &  k  \\ 
    i   & i & -1 &  k & -j  \\ 
    j   & j & -k & -1 &  i  \\ 
    k   & k &  j & -i & -1  \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]